# Does Vim Cache the Output of system()?

Tags: vimscript, macos, system

Does it? I'm not sure. I'm getting this error, and it seems to be looking for a nonexistent cache folder:

```
E282: Cannot read from "/var/folders/yh/z3ydby_56qz7mltrddsv3lqw0000gn/T/vi3voZp/0"
```

It only happens when the line that uses `system()` is uncommented out. I've already tried `histdel(':')`. I'm not sure if that also includes the `system()` function. Nothing seems to work. Is there a `histdel('*')` to delete the whole cache? I've also tried deleting lines from `.viminfo` but I'm still getting the same error. I'm using macOS Ventura. Not sure if that helps. I also tried reading the documentation but it's not mentioned there if the result of `system()` is cached or not.

```
" Read the contents of the file separated into lines
let lines = join(getline(1, '$'), '\n')

" Assign an empty string for annotations
let annotations = ''

" Separate markup from content into a list
let contents = split(lines, '\v(\<[^<]*\>|[^<]+)\zs')

" Add contents into annotations in JSON format
for i in range(len(contents))
  " Check if it's a markup or content and label it with the right key
  if match(contents[i], '<[^>]*>') > -1
    let annotations .= '{"markup":'
  else
    let annotations .= '{"text":'
  endif

 " Check if it's the last entry and put a comma after the entry if it is not
 if i < len(contents) - 1
   let annotations .= ' "' . contents[i] . '"},'
 else
   let annotations .= ' "' . contents[i] . '"}'
 endif
endfor

" Generate the JSON output
let json = '{"annotation":' . annotations . '}'

" Pass the JSON data to the LanguageTool API
let url = g:languagetool_server_root . '/v2/check'
let response = system('curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "language=' . shellescape(g:languagetool_default) . '&enabledOnly=false&data=' . shellescape(URLEncode(json)) . '"' . shellescape(url) . '"')
```

I'm not sure if it's `curl`, but from what I read, it doesn't cache on the client-side.

I tried `:set verbose=5` like @ChristianBrabandt suggested and this was the output:

```
Calling shell to execute: "(curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "language='en-US'&enabledOnly=false&data='%7b%22annotation%22%3a%
7b%22markup%22%3a+%22%3ch1%3e%22%7d%2c%7b%22text%22%3a+%22Hello+world%21%22%7d%2c%7b%22markup%22%3a+%22%3c%2fh1%3e%22%7d%7d'"'http://localhost:8081/v2/check'")>/var/folders/yh/z3ydby_56qz7mltrddsv3lqw0000
gn/T/vQGIEUY/2 2>&1"
Error detected while processing function languagetool#CheckGrammar:
line   32:
E282: Cannot read from "/var/folders/yh/z3ydby_56qz7mltrddsv3lqw0000gn/T/vQGIEUY/2"
```

Comment: no, it doesn't cache `system()` (and that wouln't make sense). However it uses tempfiles for retrieving the command output for `system()`. In your case, it looks like something on your system possibly deleted the folder where vim creates those temp files. Or the system may file for other reasons, e.g. wrong shell settings

Comment: Sorry. I meant if the output is cached. Is there anything I can do to move forward in debugging this? Like clear the list of temporary files? It's weird. It doesn't make sense to me why it stores the output. The only thing I can think of why it stores it in a temporary file is for when the output is from a remote origin. If it is, isn't it better to just say that the internet connection is required to perform the task? If it's performance reasons, it goes over my head.

Comment: The only caching that exists within Vim between `system()` calls is when the user assigns their output to a variable. `histdel()` and `.viminfo` have nothing to do with this. Give us a minimal reproducable example that we can play with in `$ vim --clean`.

Comment: Thanks! I added the related codes that are causing the error.

Comment: Use `:set verbose=5` and see what shell command vim is running. BTW: does the directory `/var/folders/yh/z3ydby_56qz7mltrddsv3lqw0000gn/T/vi3voZp` exists?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. This makes it a lot easier to debug codes. I was right. It is the `system()` function. I'll add the output to the question. About the directory, it doesn't exist. Not even `T`. I was afraid to delete `z3ydby_56qz7mltrddsv3lqw0000gn` because it has `com.apple.*` directories.

Comment: Then you need to either re-create those directories and/or configure the proper `$TEMP` for your system). And make sure, nothing is cleaning up (deleting old TEMP directories while Vim is running)

Comment: I created the directory, but it's still giving me the same error. Do I set back verbose to 0 when we're done? I read the documentation, and it said that the default is 10 but when I set it to the value, it still logs the commands.

Comment: you created `/var/folders/yh/z3ydby_56qz7mltrddsv3lqw0000gn/T/vQGIEUY/` and it still fails? Are you sure? BTW: the default for the verbose setting should be `0` (off).

Comment: I deleted another folder. I noticed that it was giving different folder names every time. This is the error currently: `E282: Cannot read from "/var/folders/yh/z3ydby_56qz7mltrddsv3lqw0000gn/T/vxYtyiD/0"`. I didn't notice it earlier.

Comment: it should only use a different folder after restart. Please make sure the folder exists

Comment: Since this is macOS, I think the `T` and such are only created when temporary directories are requested. @ChristianBrabandt do you think the folder name changes after restarting Vim or after restarting macOS? (I think neither: I recall observing different temp dirs with each call, but maybe that was a different system and Vim creates one temp dir on startup with tempfiles inside it?)

Comment: I haven't restarted macOS yet since I started this project.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble IIRC the `v*` is created uniquely after re-starting Vim. You can check: `vim --clean -c ':echo tempname()'`. The folder should be there, just the temp files will only be created on demand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147424/discussion-between-samuel-bacay-and-christian-brabandt).

Comment: I've been testing the value of `tempname()` and it seems to be creating the right folder that is set in the value every time Vim is restarted. It's just that in this particular case, it's throwing me the error that it can't find the file usually named with a single digit integer. It also changes every time. I tried creating and loading another Vimscript that uses `curl` and it worked. For some reason, it only throws the error on this one.

Comment: I hope it's fine to ask. It's somewhat related to the topic anyway. Does Vim cache Ruby modules loaded by a Vimscript?

Answer (score 0):

It worked! I reconstructed the curl command and separated the header and body (including the data to be passed) into variables. It was an issue with quotation marks. `shellescape()` encloses the variable in single quotation marks.

This is the code that worked:

```
let content_type = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
let accept = 'Accept: application/json'
let data = 'language=' . g:languagetool_default . '&enabledOnly=false&data=' . json
let url = g:languagetool_server_root . '/v2/check'
let response = system('curl -s -X POST --header ' . shellescape(content_type) . ' --header ' . shellescape(accept) . ' -d ' . shellescape(data) . ' ' . shellescape(url))
```

I still don't understand why there was a temporary file being loaded by `system()` that doesn't exist, though.

---

I spoke too soon. It's doing it again in the reconstructed `curl` command. I guess it wasn't the issue with the quotation mark that was causing the issue with the temporary files.

---

My bad. It's not related to this question.